# python create a set of data from lognorm distribution multiples of a fix number

Tags: python, numpy, apply, rounding

I would like to sample from a log-normal distribution but the sample data should be composed by multiples of fix number.

This is what I have done so far:

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
mu   = 2.0
std  = 1.5
sample = lognorm.rvs(std, size=400) * np.exp(mu)
```

This allows me to have a sample from a log-normal distribution.
I would like, however, to have the data in sample multiple of the value 0.2.

For example sample[5] = 0.23 should become 0.2 or sample[0] = 84.48 should become data[0] = 84.4.

This can be easily done as

```
r1 = round(0.2*np.floor(round(sample[0] / 0.2,2)),1)
r2 = round(0.2*np.floor(round(sample[5] / 0.2,2)),1)
```

At this point I am not able to extend the procedure to the vector. I could use a for cycle but I do not think that is the best solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the numbers first before rounding, then unscaling them. The rounding can be done in numpy for the entire array/vector:

`np.round(sample / 0.2) * 0.2`

Comment: maybe I have not understood correctly but I get this error: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method.

Comment: np is the module, not the instance of an array. Perhaps check if you have accidentally assigned to the variable `np` with an instance of an array.